# Uploading Python artifactory from jenkins to Jfrog

Tags: python, artifactory

How do I publish a python project artifactory from jenkins to jfrog.

I have a python package, I needed to build it in jenkins and upload the artifactory to Jfrog.

But the artifact says its corrupted.

What is the correct way to publish our python artifactory from jenkins to Jfrog?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, python uses the pip client to work with the packages. I would suggest referring to this [Github page](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/pip-examples) with pip jenkins example to start with.